# Getting derivatives of NNs according to its inputs by batches in JAX

Tags: python, deep-learning, jax, autograd, flax

There is a neural network that takes as an input a two variables: `net(x, t)`, where `x` is usually d-dim, and `t` is a scalar. The NN outputs a vector of length `d`. `x` and `t` might be batches, so `x` is of shape `(b, d)`, and `t` is `(b, 1)`, and the output is `(b,d)`. I need to find

- derivative `d out/dt` of the NN output. It should be d dim vector (or `(batch, d)`);
- derivative `d out/dx` of the NN
- gradient of divergence of the NN output according to `x`, it still should be `(batch, d)` vector

Since the NN doesn’t output a scalar, I don’t think Jax grad would help here. I know how to do what I described in torch, but I’m totally new to JAX. I’d really appreciate your help with this question!

There is an example:

```
import jaxlib
import jax
from jax import numpy as jnp
import flax.linen as nn
from flax.training import train_state



class NN(nn.Module):
    hid_dim : int # Number of hidden neurons
    output_dim : int # Number of output neurons

    @nn.compact  
    def __call__(self, x, t):
        out = jnp.hstack((x, t))
        out = nn.tanh(nn.Dense(features=self.hid_dim)(out))
        out = nn.tanh(nn.Dense(features=self.hid_dim)(out))
        out = nn.Dense(features=self.output_dim)(out)
        return out

d = 3
batch_size = 10
net = NN(hid_dim=100, output_dim=d)

rng_nn, rng_inp1, rng_inp2 = jax.random.split(jax.random.PRNGKey(100), 3)
inp_x = jax.random.normal(rng_inp1, (1, d)) # batch, d
inp_t = jax.random.normal(rng_inp2, (1, 1))
params_net = net.init(rng_nn, inp_x, inp_t)

x = jax.random.normal(rng_inp2, (batch_size, d)) # batch, d
t = jax.random.normal(rng_inp1, (batxh_size, 1))

out_net = net.apply(params_net, x, t)

optimizer = optax.adam(1e-3)

model_state = train_state.TrainState.create(apply_fn=net.apply,
                                            params= params_net,
                                            tx=optimizer)
```

I'd like to calculate an $L_2$ loss based on some derivatives of the NN's outputs according to its inputs. For example, I'd like to have `d f/dx` or `d f/dt` where `f` is the NN. ALso the gradient of the divergence by x. I assume it'd be something like

```
def find_derivatives(net, params, X, t):
    d_dt = lambda net, params, X, t: jax.jvp(lambda time: net(params, X, t), (t, ), (jnp.ones_like(t), ))
    d_dx = lambda net, params, X, t: jax.jvp(lambda X: net(params, X, t), (Xs_all, ), (jnp.ones_like(X), ))
    out_f, df_dt = d_dt(net.apply, params, X, t)

    d_ddx = lambda net, params, X, t: d_dx(lambda params, X, t: d_dx(net, params, X, t)[1], params, X, t)
    df_dx, df_ddx = d_ddx(net.apply, params, X, t)
    
    return out_f, df_dt, df_dx, df_ddx


out_f, df_dt, df_dx, df_ddx = find_derivatives(net, params_net, x, t)
```

Comment: You can do this using a combination of `grad` and `vmap`, but it's difficult to provide a more specific answer without example code to work with.

Comment: For example, what does it mean that in your `net` function `x` is "usually d-dim"? This is a case where the details matter, and if you edit your question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the function you want to differentiate, I'd be happy to show how to compute the quantities you're interested in.

Comment: Hey @jakevdp I've updated my question with the code example! I hope it makes sense now. What I mean: my neural network outputs a vector of length `d`, and it takes as an input a vector `x` of length d and a vector `t` of length 1 (it's actually a constant). Of course, these inputs go as batches, so there is an extra dimension, that's why I try to use `vmap` in my code. I'd really appreciate your help and insights!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using `jax.jvp` here, because this is meant as a lower-level API. You can use `jax.jacobian` to compute the Jacobian (since your function has multiple outputs), and `vmap` for batching. For example:

```py
df_dx = jax.vmap(
    jax.jacobian(net.apply, argnums=1),
    in_axes=(None, 0, 0)
  )(params_net, x, t)
print(df_dx.shape)  # (10, 3, 3)

df_dt = jax.vmap(
    jax.jacobian(net.apply, argnums=2),
    in_axes=(None,0, 0)
  )(params_net, x, t).reshape(10, 3)
print(df_dt.shape)  # (10, 3)
```

Here `df_dx` is the batch-wise Jacobian of the 3-dimensional output vector with respect to the 3-dimensional x input vector, and `df_dt` is the batch-wise gradient of the 3-dimensional output vector with respect to the input `t`.